# How to make View in a ConstraintLayout fill the available height?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm new to Android development. I created an activity/layout with two views. The first one is a custom button that I want to be 50dp high. The second is a list view that I want to take the rest of the screen below it.

[image]

My problem is that when I constrain them to each other, the `ListView` gets crushed to 0 and the "springs" around the 50dp button expand to take all the space. Here I've given the list a height of 200dp so you can see it. If I set it to "match constraint" it goes to 0. There is content in the list.

[image]

With iOS constraints I know how to do this. The constraints around the button are behaving like "greater than or equal" constraints in iOS. I want them to be "equal". How do you do this in Android?

Here's the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="false"
    tools:context=".WorkoutActivity">

    <mycompany.PlayPauseButton
        android:id="@+id/play_pause_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/workout_list"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/workout_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: going to give you a proper answer now, just waiting for android studio :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to attach the top of `listView` to the bottom of `playButton` not other way around

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="false"
    tools:context=".WorkoutActivity">

    <mycompany.PlayPauseButton
        android:id="@+id/play_pause_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/workout_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/play_pause_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks. That's a significant difference from iOS "constraints" I'm used to, where X to Y behaves like Y to X.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the ListView to occupy all of the available space, it is a good idea to set the height to 0dp. This is sorta like a stretch-me-how-you-like scheme for ConstraintLayouts. The height would therefore entirely depend on the top and bottom constraints. So, nice step!

**Your mistake, however, was the way you constrained your views.** You were supposed to constrain the ListView to the bottom of `play_pause_button` (as shown below). This way, the position of the ListView is always dependent on (and below) `playButton`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_constrainedHeight="false"
  tools:context=".WorkoutActivity">

  <mycompany.PlayPauseButton
    android:id="@+id/play_pause_button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/workout_list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/play_pause_button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

Just set the constraints the right way. No constraint bottom in the button but a constraintTop in the listview.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="false"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <mycompany.PlayPauseButton
        android:id="@+id/play_pause_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/workout_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/play_pause_button"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is working for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                   app:layout_constrainedHeight="false">

    <mycompany.PlayPauseButton
            android:id="@+id/play_pause_button"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/workout_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/play_pause_button"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

With constraint layout, it's usually (at least in my experience) a lot easier to build either top-down or bottom-up, so get one component into a position where you're happy with it and then add then next one, maybe that helps